# Saving and retrieving high-score data in XNA 4.0

Tags: xna, c#, xml, sql

I made a game in XNA 4.0 and now I need to save the points in a database or in a file (or in something else). My goal is to store and retrieve the highest score if I choose that option in the main menu. What I found on the internet is not complete, or whatever, useless for me.

What techniques can I use with XNA to save and load data?

Comment: Welcome to GD:SE. Here we like it when you make your question clear and specific. This question is too broad and is essentially asking for code. What have you tried already? If the answer is nothing then you need to come back after you have tried.

Comment: I don't need code! I just need suggestions because i don't know what to do. It is my first game.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Suggestions for what? What's wrong with saving that data in a file or a database?

Comment: I don't know what to use to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XNA you can use isolated storage to be able to store data in a cross-platform manner.

You can find the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604992.aspx it includes an example that works on both Windows, Xbox 360 and PC.

If you're only developing for Windows you can also use the normal C# IO functions like File.Create, File.Open and the stream functions to save and load data. A short tutorial can be found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304430/EN-US

Comment: Thank you very much bro! that is what i was looking for.